# Why does CodeChef's compiler complain that my code needs to throw an exception?

Tags: java, exception

When I try running the code in CodeChef's compiler it says that I need to throw some sort of exception. However the code runs fine with Eclipse and JRE 8u20. This is to solve the problem at http://www.codechef.com/problems/SNAKY. Can anybody help me?

The message I received is:

> NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code. For C users, this will be generated if your main method does not have a return 0; statement. Other languages like Java/C++ could generate this error if they throw an exception

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Snake {
int N, M, x, y, L;
String path;
public Snake(int N, int M, int x, int y, int L,String path) {
    this.N=N;
    this.M=M;
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.L=L;
    this.path=path;
}

public void snaky(){
    int[][] area =new int[M][N];
    for(int i=0;i<M;i++)
        for(int j1=0;j1<N;j1++)
            area[i][j1]=0;
    int j=2;
    Snake[] s = new Snake[L];
    for(int i=0;i<L;i++)
        s[i] = new Snake(0,0,0,0,0,path);
    s[L-1] = new Snake(0,0,x,y,0,path);
    area[x][y]=1;
    char[] moves = path.toCharArray();
    int k=0;
    while(j<=L){
        char turn=moves[k++];
        if(turn=='U'){
            s[L-j++] = new Snake(0,0,x-1,y,0,path);
            area[x-1][y]=1;
            x=x-1;
            continue;
        }
        if(turn=='D'){
            s[L-j++] = new Snake(0,0,x+1,y,0,path);
            area[x+1][y]=1;
            x=x+1;
            continue;
        }
        if(turn=='L'){
            s[L-j++] = new Snake(0,0,x,y-1,0,path);
            area[x][y-1]=1;
            y=y-1;
            continue;
        }
        if(turn=='R'){
            s[L-j++] = new Snake(0,0,x,y+1,0,path);
            area[x][y+1]=1;
            y=y+1;
            continue;
        }

    }   
    char last = moves[L-2];
    int count=1;
    if(last=='U'){
            while(x>0){
                    if(area[x-1][y]==0){
                        area[x-1][y]=1;
                        area[s[L-count].x][s[L-count].y]=0;
                        count++;
                        x=x-1;
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("BODY"+" "+(count-1));
                        return;
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("WALL"+" "+(count-1));
    }
    if(last=='D'){
        while(x<M){
                if(area[x+1][y]==0){
                    area[x+1][y]=1;
                    area[s[L-count].x][s[L-count].y]=0;
                    count++;
                    x=x+1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("BODY"+" "+(count-1));
                    return;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("WALL"+" "+(count-1));
    }
    if(last=='L'){
        while(y>0){
                if(area[x][y-1]==0){
                    area[x][y-1]=1;
                    area[s[L-count].x][s[L-count].y]=0;
                    count++;
                    y=y-1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("BODY"+" "+(count-1));
                    return;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("WALL"+" "+(count-1));
    }
    if(last=='R'){
        while(y<N){
                if(area[x][y+1]==0){
                    area[x][y+1]=1;
                    area[s[L-count].x][s[L-count].y]=0;
                    count++;
                    y=y+1;
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("BODY"+" "+(count-1));
                    return;
                }
        }
        System.out.println("WALL"+" "+(count-1));
    }   
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = reader.nextInt();
    Snake[] s = new Snake[T];
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        int N = reader.nextInt();
        int M = reader.nextInt();
        int x = reader.nextInt();
        int y = reader.nextInt();
        int L = reader.nextInt();
        String path = reader.next();
        s[i] = new Snake(N,M,M-y,x-1,L,path);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<T;i++){
        s[i].snaky();
    }
    reader.close();
}

}
```

Comment: So where does it say you need to throw an exception?

Comment: does it really say "some sort of exception"? Can you give us the exact error message?

Comment: @msrd0 NZEC stands for Non Zero Exit Code. For C users, this will be generated if your main method does not have a return 0; statement. Other languages like Java/C++ could generate this error if they throw an exception.

Comment: @msrd0 Thats the error I get

Comment: You can find the compilers used by codechef [here](http://www.codechef.com/wiki/list-compilers). It says they use `javac-1.7.0_25` for all Java programs. You might try to compile your program using jdk7

Comment: Also you might have a look at an existing solution and add the thread-technologie as well (since this seems to compile): http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/495220

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be telling you that, in some circumstances, your code will throw an exception. Clearly the competition wants you to avoid this situation.

A simple solution is to wrap your entire `main` method in a try/catch and post some message at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  try {
    // original code
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

A better solution is to figure out in what circumstances you are throwing an exception and try and avoid it where possible. That requires analysis of  your code and the underlying problem - something I'm not going to do for you.